# Extracting term from sum with index changes, where do I is misunderstood the solution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, geometric-series

It is proper solution for $ P(X > x) $ for Geometric distribution; 
$$ P(X > x) = p \sum_{k=x+1}^{\infty} (1-p)^k = p (1-p)^x \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1-p)^k = \frac{p (1-p)^x}{1-(1-p)} = (1-p)^x $$
I am wondering how to achieve $ k = 0 $ in sum. For me it looks that the $ k $ should equal 1, like this: 
$$ p \sum_{k=x+1}^{\infty} (1-p)^k = p (1-p)^x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^k $$ Because 
$$ p \sum_{k=x+1}^{\infty} (1-p)^k = p ((1-p)^{x+1} + (1-p)^{x+2} + \dots + (1-p)^{x+n} + \dots) = p (1-p)^x ((1-p)^{1} + (1-p)^{2} + \dots + (1-p)^{n} + \dots) = p (1-p)^x \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^k $$ 
Can somebody help me and tell what I am missing? I know that my solution is wrong.

Comment: Now that you've worked out $\mathbb P(X>x)$, try computing $\mathbb P(X>x+y\mid X>y)$ directly from the definition of conditional probability. You should find an interesting result.

Comment: It shows lack of memory $ (1-p)^x $. Should I expect something more? :)

Comment: That's exactly right!

Answer (score 2):

You are right. $k$ ranges from $1$ to $\infty$. The answer is $P(X>x) =(1-p)^{x+1}$.

Comment: Thank you, it helps me to find the problem. Problem is that $ P(X > x) = p \sum_{k=x+1}^{\infty} (1-p)^k$ but should be $ P(X > x) = p \sum_{k=x+1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{k - 1}$ then the result is proper $ P(X > x) = (1-p)^x $